# Can I reset RVIZ via topic?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

Is there a way to reset rviz via topic/service/...? I'd like to clear all objects e.g. when restarting a node and since the display is not at my desk, I'd like to be able to just send a trigger to reset instead of having to use a mouse.

Nikolas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225945/can-i-reset-rviz-via-topic?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2016-02-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not that I'm aware of, but you could possible write an rviz plugin that allowed you to do so.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0